# error C2228: left of '.x' must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, sfml

I am getting the error and have absolutely no idea why!

```
//create a circle shape.
sf::CircleShape shape;
shape.setRadius(25);
shape.setFillColor(sf::Color(100,250,250));

//circle collision geometry
circle circleTest(shape.getPosition.x,shape.getPosition.y,shape.getRadius())
```

Circle is the class for circle collision geometry.And it fails on the constructor

> (shape.getPosition.x,shape.getPosition.y,shape.getRadius())

I don't know why i got the error , it worked fine then all of a sudden gave me the error in the title.

Answer (score 5):

`getPosition` is a *function*. You must call it and access its return value’s members.

Comment: Yes, a function - ie: the parenthesis are missing: `shape.getPosition().x` etc...   (fixed, sorry)

Comment: PS - Parens on function calls are language dependent, so good to point out that's the problem in case they're used to SQL/VB etc.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting this error is because sf::Shape::getPosition() is a method and you need to call that method to get the position. After you make that call you can then access the .x and .y members of the sf::Vector2f that sf::Shape::getPosition() returns.

So your code should instead look like this.

```
//create a circle shape.
sf::CircleShape shape;
shape.setRadius(25);
shape.setFillColor(sf::Color(100,250,250));

//circle collision geometry
circle circleTest(shape.getPosition().x,shape.getPosition().y,shape.getRadius())
```

[sf::Shape::getPosition()](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1/classsf_1_1Transformable.php#a6a0552d8cf155b7df25f6ceda8ee45a5)